# Directory location for python 2 and 3

Tags: python, linux, cmake

In my usr/bin directory, there are 3 executable files for python - python, python27, python36

Which version of python does the python file direct to?
What argument should I pass to cmake find_program to get the python 3 version?

Comment: Well what does `python --version` tell you?

Comment: `ls -Al` is your friend. It will show you the link for `python`.

Comment: python --version shows 2.7 but whereis python shows both python2.7 and python3.5 and python files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What argument should I pass to cmake find_program to get the python 3 version? -

`find_program` searched executable by its *filename*, so you need to pass `python36` for find it.

But preferred way to find python executable is [find_package(PythonInterp)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindPythonInterp.html). That way you may specify *minimum version* and do not care about exact filename:

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3)
```